# How do a move a repo from a project to a subproject within?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I created a repo at  `mygitlab-url.com/proect/my-repo` and I want it to live here instead , Is there an easy way to move it ?

`mygitlab-url.com/sub-proect/my-repo`

Comment: what do you mean by `live here instead`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the "Transfer project" option on the project settings.

Settings >> General >> Advanced Settings >> Transfer project

Comment: unfortunately I don't see the transfer option , possible because I am master and not owner ?

Comment: @user2062360 Indeed, see https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/settings/#transferring-an-existing-project-into-another-namespace for further reference.